# How to reset a jquery function on-the-fly

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a little question for you that I don't know how to fix.
This is the situation, I am using a jQuery Slideshow (called Camera), and I combined this with an horizontal scrolling website.

When I select the page I want from the menu, the website scrolls to right and automatically I load from database a list of images in the Slideshow.

Unfortunately when I choose another section from the menu, it loads not correctly the images.

I'd like to reset the old CSS class or reset my function, I mean a reload of the entire function each time I press a button of the menu.

This is my function:

```
function swapContent(cv) {
    $(".camera").html("Loading...").show();
    var url = "evaluation_menu.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv}, function(data) {
        $(".camera").html(data).show(); 
        $('.camera').camera({
            pagination: false
        });
    });
}
```

This is how I use it:

```
<a class="next page" title="Title 1" href="#page" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('title1');"><div id="title1"></div></a>
<a class="next page" title="Title 2" href="#page" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('title2');"><div id="title2"></div></a>
```

Everytime I press a button it executes this function that reads and executes a query on the database.

I thought to use something in the onClick, but don't know what and how.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: "Unfortunately when I choose another section from the menu, it loads not correctly the images." You need to give us more detail than this - what does not loading correctly mean??? Also the marukp for the slideshow area o the page would probably be useful.

Comment: Show $(".camera") after  $('.camera').camera({}) not before it. i mean  
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv}, function(data) {
        $(".camera").html(data); 
        $('.camera').camera({
            pagination: false
        });
        $(".camera").show();
    });

Comment: Sorry prodigitalson, you are right.
The query works, the images load correctly, but every time I click on a button on the menu, it replicate the play/pause button, the thumbs and so on; instead to reset the window or the CSS class to the new button pressed.

Hope I was more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I found a little way to a possible solution, but this doesn't work as I want.

```
function swapContent(cv) {
$(".camera").html("Loading...").show();
var url = "evaluation_menu.php";
location.reload();   // reload the page
$.post(url, {contentVar: cv}, function(data) {
    $(".camera").html(data).show(); 
    $('.camera').camera({
        pagination: false
    });
  });
}
```

If I use "location.reload();" when I click on a button on the menu from the slided page, the slide refreshes but doesn't load the content

Comment: During the night I thought that it could be interesting to change the browser url without reloading the page with Ajax.
So I found this website: http://tinywall.info/2012/02/22/change-browser-url-without-page-reload-refresh-with-ajax-request-using-javascript-html5-history-api-php-jquery-like-facebook-github-navigation-menu/

I mixed my code, with this one, but unfortunately when I test the result on Opera, IE, Chrome, Safari, I can't see the images.
Only on FF I can see everything without problems.

Any Hint?